# How to make a multiple where clause with Laravel Elequent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$data = Retour::where('status','=',3)->where('rma','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->OrWhere('naam','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->OrWhere('framenummer','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->get();
```

What's wrong with this query?

It ignores the where status = 3..
and returns all the reconrds even where the status != 3..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group `orWhere()` here with closure:

```
$data = Retour::where('status', 3)
    ->where(function($q) use($searchquery) {
        $q->where('rma', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
          ->orWhere('naam', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%')
          ->orWhere('framenummer', 'like', '%'.$searchquery.'%');
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scopes` in such cases. See  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $searchQuery)
{
        return $query->where('status',3)
                     ->where('rma','LIKE', "%$searchQuery%")
                     ->orWhere('naam','LIKE', "%$searchQuery%")
                     ->orWhere('framenummer','LIKE', "%$searchQuery%");
}
```

and one more thing

its not `OrWhere` it is `orWhere`